# What factors effect how ggplot legends are ordered

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am creating a scatter plot in R where users can add or remove a horizontal line which shows a fixed reference value. In doing so, I noticed that changing the name of the reference line re-orders the legend, so that sometimes the horizontal line appears before the scatter legend elements, and sometimes afterwards.

Compare:

[image: Scenario one]

to

[image: Scenario two]

Below is a reproduceable example

```
YEAR = as.integer(rep(2010:2020,5))
SERIES_NAME = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 11)
OBS_VALUE = runif(n = 55, min = -5, max = 20)
EA = ifelse(SERIES_NAME=='A', 'Option 1', 'Option 2')

df <- data.frame(YEAR=YEAR,
            SERIES_NAME=SERIES_NAME,
            OBS_VALUE=OBS_VALUE,
            EA=EA)
```

Comment out one or the other of the two lines to produce a graph where  to name the horizontal line on the legend.

```
aaaaaaa <- "RGCUZYMSFP"  # appears above
aaaaaaa <- "IZTCYUXGBO"  # appears below
```

The graphs are then produced:

```
df %>% 
  select(YEAR,SERIES_NAME, OBS_VALUE, EA) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  ggplot2::geom_point(
    ggplot2::aes(
      x = YEAR,
      y = OBS_VALUE,
      col = EA),
    size = 2) +
  ggplot2::guides(
    color = ggplot2::guide_legend(nrow = 2, 
                                  byrow = TRUE))+ 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2010,2020,5))+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = EAMean,
                 linetype = aaaaaaa),
             size = 1, color = "black")
```

I've also noticed that changing the name of the variable changes the output. If I change the name of the variable from `aaaaaaaa` (8 times the letter a) to `aaaaaaa` (7 times the letter a) and update the code for the horizontal line accordingly, the legend re-orders

[image: Scenario 3]

Is there a way that I can be more consistent in controlling where my legend item goes?

Comment: You could set the order of the legend via scale_xxx_yyy(..., guide =  guide_legend(order = 1)) for the legend to appear on top and ... = 2 for the second and so on. According to the docs ggplot2 will choose by `... a secret algorithm` (see `?guide_legend`). (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightfully pointed out by @stefan, it depends on a 'secret algorithm'. While the outcome of the algorithm is unpredictable if the 'order' isn't set, we can reverse engineer what is does.

In [these lines](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/c89c265a57fd71f8a0288ce81037296aadc0a012/R/guide-legend.r#L227-L231) of the `guide_legend()` methods we see that a 'hash' is constructed that is (relatively) unique for a guide's title, labels, direction and name. The unpredictability here is in the hashing that can create widely different hashes for relatively similar (but not identical) input.

Later, in the [`guides_merge()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/759c63c2fd9e00ba3322c1b74b227f63c98d2e06/R/guides-.r#L232-L244) internal function, we can see that guides (or guide defitions) are splitted on their hash. Since the hashing produces the same outcome for the same input, this instructs ggplot2 whether these guides are 'mergeable' due to shared title, labels, direction and name.

What the 'order' argument does, is that the 'order' is pasted in front of the hash, so that in lexicographical order guides with `order = 0` precede guides with `order = 1`. Guides with no order argument set get `99` as order. Because splitting returns results in a sorted order depending on the split levels, this effectively sorts the output on order first, hash second.

Comment: OK, so in practice, on the above example how could I ensure that the dashed line was always on the bottom?

Comment: You can use `scale_linetype_manual(values = 2, guide = guide_legend(order = 999))`, I think.

Comment: Indeed it does! Thank you :)